# How to bind jQuery Ajax Call with dynamic parameter given from PHP via HTML

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm new to jQuery - this is my first attempt... I'm on this for two days, but can't get it to work...

There's a list, dynamically created by PHP. If the user clicks on the span-element with the fontawesome-minus-icon a XHR-Request should be fired to the API which delete the single entry. If I use a button-element the function is executed as it is, but I don't know how to get it work with dynamically added ID's, and how to pass them to the AJAX Query..

Many attemps, with functions, onclick, etc. don't work for me...

**HTML, Ajax part:**

```
   <script charset="UTF-8" type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
            $("button").click(function (e) {
                var getthevalue = $(e).attr('id');
                alert(getthevalue);
                console.log("Abfrage ob LFZ geloescht werden soll.");
                swal({
                        title: "LFZ aus Flotte loeschen?",
                        text: "Das ausgewaehlte Luftfahrtzeug wirklich aus Ihrer persönlichen Flotte loeschen?",
                        type: "warning",
                        confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
                        confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
                        cancelButtonText: "No, cancel pls!",
                        showCancelButton: true,
                        closeOnConfirm: false,
                        showLoaderOnConfirm: true,
                    },
                    function () {

                        console.log("Starte XHR Request zum loeschen eines LFZ aus der eigenen Flotte");
                        $.post("http://____/fleetdb_removeFromOwnFleet.php",
                            {
                                userId: "<? echo $toolbox_user_id; ?>",
                                userPasswd: "<? echo getUserPasswd($toolbox_user_id); ?>",
                                lfzDbId: "lalala"
                            },
                            function(data,status){
                                alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
                            });

                        setTimeout(function () {
                            swal("Ajax request finished!");
                        }, 2000);
                    });
            });
        });
        </script>
```

**HTML, dynamically outputed part:**

```
    <?
    $sql = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM `xx` WHERE `user_id`='$toolbox_user_id'");
    foreach ($sql as $dbentry) {
        $lfzId = $dbentry->lfz_id;
        $sql2 = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM `xx` WHERE `id`='$lfzId'");
        foreach ($sql2 as $lfzdbentry) {
            $dbEntryId = $lfzdbentry->id;
            $lfzReg = $lfzdbentry->reg;
            $lfzManufacturer = $lfzdbentry->manufacturer;
            $lfzType = $lfzdbentry->type;
            $lfzHomebase = $lfzdbentry->homebase;
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td>##</td>
                <td><? echo "#".$dbEntryId." "; ?><? echo $lfzReg; ?></td>
                <td><? echo $lfzManufacturer." ".$lfzType; ?></td>
                <td>
                    <span class="tooltips" style="cursor: pointer;">
                        <a rel="tooltip" data-original-title="Dieses LFZ aus der Flotte entfernen">
                            <span style=" color: #A4C62D;"><i class="fa fa-minus-square"></i></span>
                        </a>
                    </span>
                   [...morespanswithfunctions...]
                </td>
            </tr>
            <?
        }
    }
    ?>
```

How can I pass the `$dbEntryId` to the jQuery-Ajax-Call?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Option 1***

Well to start with there is no `<button>` on which you want the `click` to trigger on. So what you could do is the following:
Add a button somewhere in the html like:

```
<button class="delete" id="<? echo $dbEntryId; ?>">Delete</button>
```

Than in your jQuery:

```
$("button.delete").click(function () {
    var $this = $(this), // Pointing to the clicked element (a button in this case)
    $getTheValue = $this.attr('id');
    alert($getTheValue);
```

***Option 2***

In html edit:

```
<a rel="tooltip" data-original-title="Dieses LFZ aus der Flotte entfernen">
    <span style=" color: #A4C62D;"><i class="fa fa-minus-square"></i></span>
</a>
```

To:

```
<a class="delete" rel="tooltip" data-original-title="Dieses LFZ aus der Flotte entfernen" data-id="<? echo $dbEntryId; ?>">
    <span style=" color: #A4C62D;"><i class="fa fa-minus-square"></i></span>
</a>
```

Then in jQuery

```
$("a.delete").click(function () {
        var $this = $(this), // Pointing to the clicked element (a button in this case)
        $getTheValue = $this.data('id');
        alert($getTheValue);
```

You could also try and add Option 2 on one of the following: `span` and even on your `i icon`

I hope this helps you somewhat. If it doesn't please let me know.

Comment: Thank you very much, the second Option works directly. Great! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a unique id with each link.
Try something like this:

```
<?
    $sql = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM `xx` WHERE `user_id`='$toolbox_user_id'");
    foreach ($sql as $dbentry) {
        $lfzId = $dbentry->lfz_id;
        $sql2 = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM `xx` WHERE `id`='$lfzId'");
        foreach ($sql2 as $lfzdbentry) {
            $dbEntryId = $lfzdbentry->id;
            $lfzReg = $lfzdbentry->reg;
            $lfzManufacturer = $lfzdbentry->manufacturer;
            $lfzType = $lfzdbentry->type;
            $lfzHomebase = $lfzdbentry->homebase;
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td>##</td>
                <td><? echo "#".$dbEntryId." "; ?><? echo $lfzReg; ?></td>
                <td><? echo $lfzManufacturer." ".$lfzType; ?></td>
                <td>
                    <span class="tooltips" style="cursor: pointer;">
                        <a rel="tooltip" data-original-title="Dieses LFZ aus der Flotte entfernen">
                            <a href="javascript;" id="<?php echo $dbEntryId;?>" onclick="functioname(this.id)">
                              <span style=" color: #A4C62D;"><i class="fa fa-minus-square"></i></span>
                            </a>
                        </a>
                    </span>
                   [...morespanswithfunctions...]
                </td>
            </tr>
            <?
        }
    }
    ?>
```

And in jQuery call the function and get the id. Now you can use this id:

```
functionname(id){

    alert(id);
}
```